# Wrapping a Tuple of Vectors in C++ into a Tuple

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, compiler-errors

I'm trying to wrap a tuple of two vectors into a tuple in C++, but can't
decode the cryptic compiler error message.

Here is the snippet (forgive me for the using directive):

```
using namespace std;    
make_tuple( tuple< vector<int>, vector<int> >() )
```

This is the error message in Visual Studio 2010

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\tuple(127): error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(const std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::tr1::_Nil' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty> &'
          with
          [
              _Ty=int
          ]
          Reason: cannot convert from 'std::tr1::_Nil' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty>'
          with
          [
              _Ty=int
          ]
          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\tuple(127) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Cons_node<std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&>(_Farg0,_Farg1,_Farg2,_Farg3,_Farg4,_Farg5,_Farg6,_Farg7,_Farg8,_Farg9)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Car=std::vector<int>,
              _Cdr=std::tr1::_Tuple_type<std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil>::_Type,
              _Farg0=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg1=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg2=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg3=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg4=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg5=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg6=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg7=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg8=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg9=std::tr1::_Nil &
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxtuple0(9) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Cons_node<const std::vector<_Ty>&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&,std::tr1::_Nil&>(_Farg0,_Farg1,_Farg2,_Farg3,_Farg4,_Farg5,_Farg6,_Farg7,_Farg8,_Farg9)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Car=std::vector<int>,
              _Cdr=std::tr1::_Cons_node<std::vector<int>,std::tr1::_Tuple_type<std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil>::_Type>,
              _Ty=int,
              _Farg0=const std::vector<int> &,
              _Farg1=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg2=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg3=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg4=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg5=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg6=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg7=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg8=std::tr1::_Nil &,
              _Farg9=std::tr1::_Nil &
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\tuple(86) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1>::tuple<const std::vector<_Ty>&>(_Farg0)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Arg0=std::vector<int>,
              _Arg1=std::vector<int>,
              _Ty=int,
              _Farg0=const std::vector<int> &
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\tuple(389) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Car,_Cdr>::_Cons_node<_Arg0,std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Arg0,_Cdr>>(const std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Arg0,std::tr1::_Cons_node<_Arg0,_Cdr>> &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Car=std::tr1::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<int>>,
              _Cdr=std::tr1::_Tuple_type<std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil>::_Type,
              _Arg0=std::vector<int>
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxtuple1(18) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2,_Arg3,_Arg4,_Arg5,_Arg6,_Arg7,_Arg8,_Arg9>::tuple<std::vector<_Ty>,std::vector<_Ty>,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil,std::tr1::_Nil>(std::tr1::tuple<std::vector<_Ty>,std::vector<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Arg0=std::tr1::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<int>>,
              _Arg1=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg2=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg3=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg4=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg5=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg6=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg7=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg8=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg9=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Ty=int
          ]
          main.cpp(19) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2,_Arg3,_Arg4,_Arg5,_Arg6,_Arg7,_Arg8,_Arg9> std::tr1::make_tuple<std::tr1::tuple<std::vector<_Ty>,std::vector<_Ty>>>(_Arg0)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Arg0=std::tr1::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<int>>,
              _Arg1=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg2=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg3=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg4=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg5=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg6=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg7=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg8=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Arg9=std::tr1::_Nil,
              _Ty=int
          ]
```

What is wrong with my code ?

<strike>EDIT:
If I'm explicitly stating the result type, then it works.</strike>

```
make_tuple<tuple<tuple< vector<int>> >>( tuple< vector<int> >() );
```

EDIT:
False alarm, it doesn't compile either if I state the type for `make_tuple`.

```
make_tuple<tuple<tuple< vector<int>, vector<int> > >>( tuple< vector<int>, vector<int> >() );
```

Comment: [Compiled for me.](http://ideone.com/lp5cjT)

Comment: Can you post an SSCCE (see sscce.org)? My version of your code compiles on GCC 4.7.3.

Comment: OP uses VS2010 which doesn't support that...

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2010, it may be a problem :P I try to compile it in a barebone project.

Comment: @Jarod42 Doesn't support what ? I mean, what is the problem ? I see, it can not resolve the exact type, but what is the cause ?

Comment: My oh my... C++ syntactic sugar crust has crumbled and we can even see bits of LISP squirming in the goo :)

Comment: Is `std::tr1` stil used? It's only for work-in-progress libraries. Compiler might be old.

Comment: @Jarod42 False alarm, it doesn't compile even if I state the type in a stripped down project.

Comment: @A Person my compiler version is `Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86`, isn't it recent enough for a vs2010 compiler ?

Comment: It's a compiler bug, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015419/c-value-type-not-work-for-stdtr1tuple-in-a-stdmap, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374634/code-compiles-with-g-but-fails-with-vc-10

Comment: It seems I can not store anything else beside a vector in a tuple. (int, vector<int>) doesn't work either.

Comment: @A Person Thanks, but we can not upgrade right now. Believe me, I would like to, I'm starving for variadic templates:/ I'm looking for a workaround now.

Answer (score 0):

I get some strange error messages if I copy that code snippet

```
make_tuple( tuple< vector<int>, vector<int> >() );
```

with c++ 4.3.3. But if I call make_tuple as it should be called with a pair of vector variables all is well:

```
vector<int> v1;
vector<int> v2;
tuple< vector<int>, vector<int> > vecvec = make_tuple( v1, v2 );
```

And so does this:

```
int x;
tuple< int, vector<int> > intvec = make_tuple( x, v1 );
```

Comment: "But if I call make_tuple _as it should be called_ ", you miss the point here. I'm not trying to create a tuple of two vectors, but a tuple of a tuple of two vectors, there are **2 layers of tuple** here :)

Comment: If you call make_tuple with a single tuple and make_tuple forwards this to the constructor of tuple: the constructor will be a copy constructor - or do I miss something here?

Comment: No, `make_tuple` is essentially a tuple constructor function, but you don't have to explicitly tell the types. `make_tuple` accepts a (theoretically) variadic number of arguments, and returns a tuple, that has the same number of arguments, with the values you provided. So e.g: `make_tuple(5,4)` is equivalent to `std::tuple<int,int>(5,4)`, and `make_tuple(make_tuple(5))` is equivalent to `std::tuple<std::tuple<int>> (std::tuple<int>(5))`. Check out the signature of `make_tuple`.